# Why do we have $dF(T_{(p,s)}W)=T_qX$?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

[image]

Why do we have $dF(T_{(p,s)}W)=T_qX$?

Comment: Apply $dF$ to both sides of the result of problem 6.10 in Lee. Or are you asking  for a solution to the problem ?

Comment: @Matematleta Can you give more details?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is your question.

Comment: @Matematleta red rectangle

Comment: Just apply $dF$ to both sides of the equation above the one in the red rectangle.

Comment: @Matematleta But it gets $\subset$, not $=$.